# Why does PHP date('m', strtotime('-1 months')) not work correctly for today? 07/31

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a script that gets the current and last month in PHP like so:

```
$currentMonth = date('m');
//Expected:07
//Result:07
$lastMonth = date('m', strtotime('-1 months'));
//Expected:06
//Result:07
```

Today happens to be the 31 or end of the month of July. Is this result to be expected from PHP?

When using -31 days the result is as expected:

```
$lastMonth = date('m', strtotime('-31 days'));
//Expected:06
//Result:06
```

Comment: month-math is always risky. what IS a month? "today in ($curmonth-1)"?, what happens if it's march 31st, do you want february 31st, or feb 28? feb 29?

Comment: Looks like those aren't the only days `-1 month` breaks on: http://codepad.viper-7.com/E4gP0W  The 31st of a month don't surprise me, but the 29th and 30th of March do.

Comment: Always amazed when I find someone still not using https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon to do dates in PHP.

Comment: @ceejayoz Carbon reacts the same in this case https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/37

Comment: @Subie I'm still surprised though. So much easier.

Comment: Not just php, but also gnu http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [cleaner test case](http://3v4l.org/F1fWN) that doesn't expire:

```
<?php
$origin = mktime(18, 0, 0, 7, 31, 2015);
var_dump( date('r', $origin), date('r', strtotime('-1 months', $origin)) );
```

```
string(31) "Fri, 31 Jul 2015 18:00:00 +0200" 
string(31) "Wed, 01 Jul 2015 18:00:00 +0200"
```

I'm pretty sure it's a documentation issue, because the manual clearly states this (emphasis mine):

> Relative month values are calculated **based on the length of months**
>   that they pass through. An example would be "+2 month 2011-11-30",
>   which would produce "2012-01-30". This is due to November being 30
>   days in length, and December being 31 days in length, producing a
>   total of 61 days.

... and it's wrong.

PHP bug tracker has [tons of dupes](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22-1%20month%22%20site:bugs.php.net) about this. They're all closed as *not a bug*. Here's a relevant [comment from 2009](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22486#1246615630) that explains it:

> I agree that this is an annoying behaviour.
>
> Also, the implementation is problematic. Basically **if you use '+1
>   month' it takes the month number, adds 1 and parses result as a new
>   date**.
>
> If you use '+1 month' on the first of the month, it sets the date to
>   the next first of the month.
>
> This behaviour gives the impression, that php considers the length of
>   a month, which is not true.
>
> **But if you use '+1 month' on the last day of a month, the result is
>   unexpected** as 2009-05-31 becomes 2009-06-31 which is an invalid date
>   and then interpreted as 2009-07-01.
>
> This **should at least be mentioned in the documentation**.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way

```
$d = new DateTime(); 
$currentMonth = $d->format('m');
//Expected:07
//Result:07
print $currentMonth;

$d->modify('first day of previous month');
print "<br/>";
$lastMonth = $d->format('m'); 
//Expected:06
//Result:06
print $lastMonth;
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kokWi8

Answer (score 2):

This is a issue with PHP's date-string parser. See here:
http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html

@Mr. Llama made a script showing what other dates this issue  effects:http://codepad.viper-7.com/E4gP0W

The solution I went with:

```
//Date:07/31/15
$currentMonth = date('m');
//Result:07
$lastMonth = date('m', strtotime('first day of -1 months'));
//Result:06
```

Comment: Great answer to a perplexing problem.

Answer (score 1):

`-1 month` is interpreted as "same day of month, last month". If this day does not exist, the date overflows into the next month. Actually the result is the same as `strtotime("31.6.2015")` - try it!

Answer (score -1):

There is **"s"** in excess in month. It should be like this:

```
$lastMonth = date('m', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

Comment: makes no difference. PHP isn't a grammar nazi and `1 months` and `1 month` are identical as far as it's concerned.

Comment: Indeed, the extra `s` is allowed/optional. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) confirms that.